# ASP.Net Web API 2 attribute-routed HTTP POST action not getting correct parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a simple ASP.Net Web API 2 controller:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/method/{msg?}")]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public string Method(string msg = "John")
    {
        return "hello " + msg;
    }
}
```

And a simple HTML form to test it.

```
<form action="/api/method/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="msg" value="Tim" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I load the page and submit the form the resulting string is `"hello John"`. If I change the form's method from `post` to `get` the result changes to `"hello Tim"`. Why hasn't the `msg` parameter been routed to the action when posted to the controller?

========== EDIT 1 ==========

Just-in-case the HTTP GET is distracting, this version of the controller also fails to receive the correct `msg` parameter from the posted form:

```
[Route("api/method/{msg?}")]
[HttpPost]
public string Method(string msg = "John")
{
    return "hello " + msg;
}
```

========== EDIT 2 ==========

I have not changed the default routing and so it still looks like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using the same method for both GET and POST requests? Typically GET would be used for retrieving a resource and UPDATE / POST would be used for modifying it. In that context it makes very little sense for the method to accept both verbs - If I had to hedge a bet, your issue would be a non issue if you separated this out too two methods.

Comment: The real app will probably just use POST, but GET are easier to just paste as URLs in the browser. So unless there's a good reason to differentiate I don't bother.

Comment: Depends if you consider the violation of REST principles a good reason not too... I would!

Comment: Indeed, though that's not what I'm asking. I've edited the question to include an POST only controller for you.

Comment: Have you changed the default routing config? If so, please post it as well.

Comment: @su8898 I have not, but I'll include it as another edit anyway just-in-case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters in `POST` methods won't be deserialized out of the box if you are using an html `form`. [Use the `[FromBody]` attribute](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) to get the value of `msg`.

```csharp
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/method")]
public string Method([FromBody] string msg)
{
    return "hello " + msg;
}
```

Otherwise you must use `Fiddler` (or a similar web debugger) to make a call to the `POST` method and pass the `msg` as a querystring.

If you really like to use an `HTML Form` without using `[FromBody]` attribute, try the following

```csharp
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/method")]
public string Method()
{
    var msg = Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
    var res= msg.Result["msg"];
    return "hello " + res ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly `[FromBody]` does not seem to work with optional parameters. E.g. if I change the code to `public string Method([FromBody] string msg = "John")` then the call fails with an `InvalidOperationException` with the message "Optional parameter 'msg' is not supported by 'FormatterParameterBinding'"

Comment: I've found that a workaround for `[FromBody]` with an optional simple type parameter is to not make it optional  and to structure your request body differently depending on whether you have values for your optional parameters:

`=stringvalue` then `msg` will be `"stringvalue"` in WebAPI.  
`msg=` then `msg` will be `null` in WebAPI.

You would have to define your default value of `"John"` inside your controller method but this would eliminate the `InvalidOperationException`.  Don't forget to set your `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`